# Need recommendation for ArcGIS Engine,ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE interview question

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

I am preparing for GIS interview.I am looking for good ArcGIS Engine,ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE interview questions. I just googled some,but the questions that I found are not that much detailed to the technology. Can anyone recommend me something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain how you would get from a Map to the data source for one of the layers in an MXD document. You can use VBA, .NET, or Java.

Explain difference between using the ServerObject to get a map versus MapServerBindingStub - which do you use and when? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each.

What is the difference between the .NET and JAVA ADF versus the JS and Silverlight APIs.

What is the difference between ArcGIS Server and ArcSDE.

write java code to buffer a point in SDE

Write .NET code to create a geoprocessing tool (or at least explain how it might be done)

Explain some of the tradeoffs in creating a performant versus pretty map

Answer (score 0):

1. Explain the difference between ArcGIS Server standard and advanced.
2. Your customer wants to write a field based GIS application, what technology do you choose ArcEngine, ArcGIS Desktop, ArcMobile or ArcPad, pros and cons of each.(no real right answer)
3. What is the difference between ST_Geometry and SDO_Geometry.
4. Explain how the REST API, differs from the SOAP API and ArcObjects.

Of course this all depends on the job they will be expected to do. In interviews I prefer to get an idea of what projects with GIS the person has done, explaining why they took certain choices, what went wrong, what would they do if they could do it again.